# How To Override Auto-enter Timestamp In FileMaker

Tags: filemaker

I have created a `Timestamp` field in a FileMaker Pro 11 database and set the field (under File>Manage>Database) to auto-enter a Modification Timestamp (Date and Time) into the field.

I want to override this auto-enter value during data entry by typing a timestamp myself, but upon commit, FileMaker replaces what I type with an auto-enter timestamp. This is the same for updating the field as well.

Is this possible to do somehow?

Comment: Yes, but the answer will depend upon the exact behavior that you want. Do you want the Creation Timestamp and then to be able to override manually from there, or do you want the Modification Timestamp sometimes and an manually overwritten timestamp others? When do you want to capture the timestamp automatically?

Comment: I want the Modification Timestamp sometimes and an manually overwritten timestamp others

Comment: The Modification Timestamp will update any time any field in the record changes... So how will the database know when you want to get the last Modification time and how will it know when to retain the manually overwritten time?

Comment: Makes sense dude. I would like it to retain value if i updated it, otherwise insert timestamp. You could post an answer saying its not possible... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offhand I can't think of a way to do this with only one field. A three-field solution would work fairly easily, however.

Create 3 fields:

1. Modification Timestamp (set to auto-enter Modification Timestamp)
2. Override Timestamp (set to type: Timestamp)
3. Display Timestamp (set to the calculation below:)

Display Timestamp:

```
// If Override Timestamp is Empty, show Modification Timestamp.
// Otherwise show Override Timestamp.
If ( IsEmpty ( Override Timestamp ) ;
     Modification Timestamp ;
     Override Timestamp )
```

Then you place Override Timestamp underneath Display Timestamp. Set Override Timestamp to be enterable only in Browse mode. Set Display Timestamp to be enterable only in Find mode.

From the UI perspective the two fields will seem to be the same field, but you'll get the desired result.